# Two website two different layout invoices

Tags: multistore, invoice

How to edit two different separated invoices layout for two website in multistore magento configuration? Is that possible?

So in global.. is it possible to change core magento files according to website or store view?

For my example to edit core invoice layout file ( Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice class ) in for example [that way](http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-magento-pdf-invoice-and-packingslip/) according to website or store view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to edit two different separated invoices layout for two website in
>   multistore magento configuration? Is that possible?

The default Magento pdfs are fairly limited - the only setting available are logo, address and if you want to display the order id. These are multistore capable.

> So in global.. is it possible to change core magento files according
>   to website or store view?
>
> For my example to edit core invoice layout file (
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice class ) in for example that way
>   according to website or store view?

It would certainly be possible to apply different logic based on store view. It depends a little bit on the extend of changes you had in mind - however using the blog post you linked to in your override of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice` you could use something like

```
switch ($order->getStoreId()) {
 case 1:
    //your custom invoice layout for store view 1
    break;
 case 2:
    //your custom invoice layout for store view 2
    break;
 default:
    //your custom invoice layout for all other store views
}
```